# How to insert space in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am facing issue when I try to insert space using `.html()` method in JQuery. 
Following is my code :

```
html += '<td >'+description+". "+location;
html += +" "+position;
html += +" &nbsp; "+side+'</td>'; 
$('#tempResult').html(html);
```

The result I am getting is as follows: 
    `Green Tint. 0FrontNaNRight`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `+` operator from your string. `+=` takes care of the string concatenation, so the additional `+` sign simply tries to make the string positive (causing the interpreter to change it to `NaN` - not a number).

`a += b` is a "shorthand way" (perhaps a simplification) of saying `a = a + b`.

```
html += '<td >'+description+". "+location;
html += " "+position;
html += " &nbsp; "+side+'</td>'; 
$('#tempResult').html(html);
```

Comment: My bad, I tried a lot, but didn't notice the extra plus sign. Thanks a lot @nbrooks, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The += + bit is doing some type conversion. Get rid of the 2nd +.

Another way of building html is via arrays and joining. One example:

```
var description = 'DESCRIPTION',
    location = 'LOCATION',
    position = 'POSITION',
    side = 'SIDE',
    html = [
        '<td>' + description,
        '. ' + location,
        ' ' + position,
        ' ' + side,
        '</td>'
    ];

$('#tempResult').html(html.join(''));
```